# Parent and child div next to each other without using position:absolute

Tags: html, css, position

Is there a way to position a parent and a child element next to each other (as if they weren't parent and child and floating left) without using position:absolute on the child element? Both parent and child should have dynamic width relative to the grandparent element.

**HTML**

```
<div id="grandparent">
   <div id="parent">
      <div id="child">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#grandparent {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
#parent {
width: 10%; /* relative to grandparent */
height: 100%;
background-color:red;
}
#child {
width: 90%; /* relative to grandparent */
height: 100%;
background-color:green;
}
```

I don't want to use jquery. JavaScript would be ok though. In the end it should look as if parent and child were both child to the "grandparent" element and floating left.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using JS to do this would start by removing the `position:absolute`. If you need to calculate the width, just do that with JS.

Comment: maybe this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/L3cxP/ , note that the width of `#child` should be 9 times larger than the `#parent`, so it should be `900%` (not `90%`).

Comment: Are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/5kKnp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did this using css and I attached a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeRL6/). Basically, I made the `#child` element 900% of it's parent and also gave it a `margin-left` of the width of the parent, so they didn't overlap. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would wnat to make `#child` **9** times larger than the `#parent` because you set `#parent` width to 10%

Change:

```
width: 90%; /* relative to grandparent */
```

to

```
width: 900%; /* relative to grandparent */
```