# CSS: Position child indepently from parent without using position:absolute

Tags: css, dynamic, position

I created a css hover menu with only one level.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="item1">item1
      <div id="content1"> </div>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">item2
      <div id="content2"> </div>
    </li>
    <li id="item3">item3
      <div id="content3"> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu {
    width: 0%;
    padding-left: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
#menu:hover {
    width: 20%;
}
#content1, #content2, #content3 {
    width: 300%;
    height: 1000%;
    margin-left: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    visibility: hidden;
    left:16px;
}
#item1:hover #content1, #item2:hover #content2, #item3:hover #content3 {
    visibility: visible;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#item1, #item2, #item3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    display:none;
}
#menu:hover #item1, #menu:hover #item2, #menu:hover #item3 {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Bv6C/12/

The menu is hidden at first but will show when you hover over it. The content boxes will show, wenn you hover over the menu items. My problem is: I would like all the content boxes (green background) to show at the same position (top:0 relative to body; left:/*width of #menu*/) and not relative to their parents (#item1,2,3). All elements should maintain dynamic width and height.

Is this possible with css? If not could I use jquery or js?

Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you want to use absolute position?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parent and child div next to each other without using position:absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432773/parent-and-child-div-next-to-each-other-without-using-positionabsolute)

Comment: @Paulie_D: its not really a duplicate. its more of a follow-up question. I didn't know how to do that, so I started a new question.

Comment: @StephenR: Because when I use absolute position on the child element, its left position won't adapt to the width of #menu element.

Comment: @user3779564 Why not? You explicitly set the width of the `#menu` to 20% (at least in your provided JSFiddle). So you know about the width ..., where is the problem?

Comment: @StephenR OK, I should have said, that I want to use transitions on the width of the #menu element and on the visibility (and opacity) of the #content divs. Without that, your solution works fine. But in my case I had to do it like chloelonan suggested and it works marvelously. check out my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Bv6C/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `position:absolute` to solve your problem. An absolutely positioned item calculates its' point of reference as the closest parent with the `position:relative` style. I updated your fiddle with the changes so you can see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/6Bv6C/13/